# Could there be a one-page (or more) of alphabetical listing of tags to quickly scan to use on questions?

Tags: support, tags

When seeking tags for a question, often there isn't any such tag, so a person has to erase and start over listing tags, only to be rejected again.  If there were a single page listing, a quick scan would facilitate a search for the most appropriate tag quickly. (Tags that are already accepted.)

The present display of page after page of tags is informational, so I wouldn't want it abandoned, though.

I am quite familiar with the display in the Answer by Glorfindel. So, what is proposed is a couple of pages of tag listings on a site, such as Christianity SE or Literature SE, that has four or five columns of listings. Each page could hold 280 tags easily in four or five columns; and depending on the font used, many more could be listed:
alpha
beta
church
conjunction
delta
ecstasy
freedom
forever
glorfindel, etc.

I realize hundreds of tags are on each site...but that is just my point.  There are so many pages to look through to find the most appropriate tag, that it is too time-consuming. One or two comprehensive pages of listings would be of the essence.

Comment: "_often there is no such tag so a person has to erase and start over listing tags_" what? can't you just click the delete "x" button of the non-existant tag? And you should clarify in the question that the person in question doesn't have enough rep to create tags.

Comment: There are about 1.7k tags on Meta.StackEachange alone. You could fit them on one page but I don't think that would work for "a quick scan".

Comment: @VLAZOf course, I was not suggesting one page for ALL Meta SE, but that each site have a listing! Those on Hermeneutics.SE could have a listing...and those tags on Science.SE have another listing, etc.

Comment: BH has 478 tags, which is a medium amount for a site. Other sites (and just the main site at that) have thousands of tags. (See full [list of sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/).) It is not practical for most sites to have a list of all tags on one page.

Comment: @Laurel-Thank you for your info.  Even a couple of pages with 250 word (tags) each would be a big help. Four or five columns with 65 tags each, on a page? A small enough font would easily facilitate this. Peace.

Comment: When you start typing in a tag, you get a popup with existing tags similar to what you're typed. If you don't get a popup, there is no such tag. So I don't understand the *"start over listing tags, only to be rejected again"* part.

Comment: This is from [math.meta.se] - but I think that the advice given there might be useful on other sites too: [How am I supposed to use tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21801) The answers contain some advice about things which can help to choose suitable tags when posting a question.

Answer (score 8):

There is a page like that, though you have to select the right tab (Name) on the right:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name (substitute `meta.stackexchange.com` with the site of your choice)

[image]

You might have to open it in a second browser tab or window while composing your question; it's not something available when composing or editing a question.